# How do I ask for answers that don't exist in the answers in other questions?

Tags: discussion

Question I just asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607369/webforms-what-are-the-options-for-an-entry-point-in-client-script-for-url-dat

Right now I've edited it in hopes that it will get reopened, but you can check the edits. The crux of the issue is that I've asked a question for which I don't feel existing answers are sufficient and I'd like to have someone vet the options I've already thought out in my head. I could change the question to "how do I work this???!?" but that means either people waste time and energy posting answers that I am not looking for, or it gets closed as a duplicate.

How do I ask for more options, or is this not appropriate for Stack Overflow?

If it's not appropriate, where can I post it without getting beaten over the head? It doesn't meet Code Review's requirements for a complete example and I'm fairly certain if I ask it on Programmers I am going to run into the same "opinion-based" problem as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Step 1:**   Identify why the other answers aren't sufficient for you.

**Step 2:**  Ask your question, but ask it in a way that makes it clear that those answers aren't sufficient.

- Don't be vague and uncertain-sounding by asking for "More options that I've overlooked"  That will get your question closed as too broad or opinion based.  Just make your need clear.

So the form of your question should be

> How do I Do X while *[meeting requirement that makes answer A insufficient]*, and *[meeting requirement that makes answer B insufficient]*?

Answer (score 7):

Your question being on hold due to "primarily opinion-based" is still correct.

Your title is the first give-away:

> what are the options for

Then in the question you go on to say:
"*what are my options* when getting request-based data into client-side execution? Here are *the approaches I've come up with*, but *I'm not satisfied with any of them*."

You can't really have such a question or approach in Stack Overflow.
To ask on SO, you should be at the stage of something like:
"I am satisfied with the approach/I have chosen option 2, but am struggling because it does not XYZ" OR "because this code ABC doesn't work because..."

But instead you are asking "Any other options I'm overlooking?" - we cannot tell you what code or approach you should be using - that is "*opinion based*".

You need to tell us what code you are using, and why it does not work, or what it should do, etc etc.

---

If you want to ask *best practice*, try another site, perhaps **[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)**.
(conceptual questions about software development)

You can ask questions along the lines of "Which is better", but really only if the possible answers are not opinion based, and are in fact "2 is better because".
eg
"I want to access a mysql database, should I use 1) `mysql_` or 2) `mysqli or PDO`?"
There is a clear answer there, mysqli/PDO, because "the other is depreciated etc blah".

Although if you asked "Should I used PDO or Mysqli" you might be stretching it towards opinion based and not answerable due to technical reasons.

In all, what you are asking is a grey area, but have a look at some of the questions on the other sites to see what is acceptable, like Programmers, and see if you can fit your question into their acceptable scope.

Comment: It's a best practices question to be sure. Let's see how I fare on programmers...

Comment: @moarboilerplate That was merely a *suggestion*, please do read their guidelines first, and peruse some of their question. There are already plenty of questions on hold for off-topic and opinion-based, so you can easily get an idea of what is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Best answer I can give is that you should make it clear that you actually looked there and there. In my opinion if you give clear reference to the existing questions and explain why it didn't make it often clarifies things.

It's often more work to formulate the question, but most often if existing answers don't cut it, it's also a more specific question. Existing answers therefore can help to draw the line in a sharp way what differences yours from the existing questions.